# Node.js: Domain module in v0.8

Tags: node.js, module, dns

I want to ask something about the new module 'Domain' in node v0.8.

```
var domain = require('domain');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var dm = domain.create();

dm.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Catch some error: ', err.message);
});

var emitter = new EventEmitter();
emitter.on('test', function() {
    throw new Error('Emit an error !');
});
dm.add(emitter);
// emitter.emit('test');                         <- This line

dm.run(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        throw new Error('Timeout !');
    }, 10);
});
```

outputs:

```
Catch some error:  Timeout !
```

And if adding the line

```
emitter.emit('test');
```

Then outputs:

```
Catch some error:  Emit an error !
```

So my question is why it does not output "Catch some error:  Timeout !" after adding the above line ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

execution here does not reach `dm.run(function() {` at all, you have to add handlers to domain before any exception happens.

Compare with

```
var domain = require('domain');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var dm = domain.create();

dm.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Catch some error: ', err.message);
});

var emitter = new EventEmitter();
emitter.on('test', function() {
    throw new Error('Emit an error !');
});
dm.add(emitter);    
dm.run(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        throw new Error('Timeout !');
    }, 10);
});
emitter.emit('test');
```

output:

```
Catch some error:  Emit an error !
Catch some error:  Timeout !
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrey. Is that mean the 'emitter' can not emit the 'test' event twice if adding one more line "emitter.emit('test');" in your code? After emitting the first time, all the following code will not be execute?

Comment: in the following example `expression1; expression2; throw new Error(); expression3` expression3 is never executed - this is basically what you have in your code

Comment: Yes, that's it. That means using a domain forms something like (exp1, exp2, throw new Error(); exp3...) and I can not emit a event twice or more in the same scope any more.

Comment: `dm.run(function() { expr1; setTimeout(function() { throw Error('1'); }, 1); expr2; throw Error('2'); expr3 });` - dm will emit 'error' twice here. If you just wrap function in try/catch you get only Error('2') in comparison with domain where you get all exceptions as 'error' events.